# Amazon Gateway API and JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm a bit of noob at this subject.
So I have a servlet and jsp that can take in a url argument like this:

```
url/registeruser/?username=username&password=password
```

And when I use that url scheme directly to the browser it works. But when I attempt to build a AWS Gateway API for this using POST or GET I get a response that JAVA did not receive any parameter arguments.

The way I built my API gateway was to try a post and get request. 
And I tried using query strings of username and password
and with header parameters of username and password

Both times did not work.

Is there something I am not understanding about a JAVA security measure or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that you're not correctly mapping your incoming request to the API Gateway to the corresponding request for your HTTP backend.  Assuming you're using the UI to configure your API Gateway:

1. Select the appropriate Resource and HTTP Method on the left (e.g. `/registeruser` `POST`)
2. Select "Method Request"
3. Under "URL Query String Parameters", add the query string vars you want to pass to your HTTP backend.
4. Now go back a screen and select "Integration Request".  Now add your query string variable again, but under "Mapped from" enter `method.request.querystring.myparam`.

Now your HTTP backend will receive the query string param specified with the given value as pulled from your initial request to the API Gateway.

Comment: That was the piece of information i was missing. Thanks. I want to add for anyone else that might read this that '.myparam' maps to the query strings you made in method request. So in my case 'myparam' would be both 'username'  and 'password' .